# two sites with different names established on one Joomla base, how to use facebook like bottom on both of them?

Tags: facebook, joomla, facebook-comments, facebook-likebox

I have one site - example.com and ones mirror - example2.com. Both sites are completely similar and are established on one Jomla's base.
I have like bottom with ID to example.com and on the example2.com this bottom doesn't work (because of wrong ID).

Is it possible to solve this problem - to have two site names and wotking facebook like bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the ID and look into documenation on how to generate Like button. Here is [Facebook Like Button API documentation/generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

Like button takes URL as parameter. So simply do this:

1. Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
2. Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

On Site #1:

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example1.com" data-send="true"
data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

On Site #2:

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example2.com" data-send="true"
data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

Or more dynamic:

`<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>`

Or Joomla Specific, get live_site configuration from config and display it:

```
$cfg -> reference to Joomla Config
<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?php echo $cfg->live_site; ?>" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```